# UIWebView hiding when loading a full html page in, but NOT when omitting certain tags?

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

My UIWebView is displaying some strange behavior.  When I load in a full HTML page, it just shows me a blank page.  If I were, however, to load in just something like "Hi," it will display fine.  my code is as follows for loading it:

```
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://site.com/external/get.php?type=phone&url=%@", url]] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

Assume that the html is valid, and it will always return a result if you just type in the url.  That current code displays a blank UIWebView, but if I were to configure that url to just display "Hi," it would display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having an encoding error. You specified, that your source would be UTF-8 encoded, which it is not.

## Option 1

What is wrong with letting the UIWebView handle the request itself? It would be way easier and you don't have to mess around with encodings.

```
NSString *urlstring = @"http://some.url.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlstring];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webview loadRequest:request];
```

## Option 2

Try using `NSASCIIStringEncoding` instead of `NSUTF8StringEncoding`. Has worked out for a quick test for me. Other NSStringEncoding enumerations can be found here: http://api.monobjc.net/html/T_Monobjc_Foundation_NSStringEncoding.htm

## For the Future:

Don't ignore the error.

```
NSError *error;
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://site.com/external/get.php?type=phone&url=%@", url]] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
if (error)
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
```

In your case, this would most likely have printed out `Cocoa error 261` to the console. That this means that you have a wrong encoding, can be easily found out through google and/or stackoverflow.

Also, try to debug your application, when having problems like this. The problem was the String being nil, not the WebView malfunctioning.